How to create a plot on r with ggplot without the x-axis automatically plotting in alphabetical order?
I am trying to create a plot with the following code.
df = data.frame(data)
 
df$date <- paste(data$Year, data$Month, sep="_")
print(df)

df_new <- df[c("date", "BrisMaxTemp", "GoldCoastMaxTemp")]
print(df_new)

ggplot(df_new, aes(x = date, y = BrisMaxTemp)) +
  geom_point() + ylab("Bris Max Temp (°C)") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text( angle = 90, color="Black", size=10, face=3)) +
  ggtitle("Brisbane Max temps over time") + xlab("Year_Month")

However, when I plot, it plots like Apr_2015, Aug_2015 (in alphabetical order essentially), instead of Jan_2015, Feb_2015 etc (month by month order).
I have tried to use the factor function to fix this however that isn't working. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Welcome to SO! factor is the way to go. But you have to specify the order of the levels, i.e. df$date <- factor(df$date, levels = c("Jan_2015", "Feb_2015", ...) though I would guess that there are easier ways to achieve that instead of passing a (long) list of  levels. For more help please provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

If your observations have gaps, you might want to show your data on a chronological scale by converting df$date to a "Date" type with something like df$date = as.Date(paste(df$Year, df$Month, "01"), format = "%Y %b %d")

Does this answer your question? Avoid ggplot sorting the x-axis while plotting geom_bar()
